# Cloudflare SSL not working even though it worked before

Tags: python, django, ssl

Cloudflare SSL is not working on my website (made with Django, hosted on heroku).

I used GoDaddy but then transferred the Nameserver stuff to Cloudflare to get SSL.

It worked yesterday, but now for some reason, it isn't.

On Cloudflare I have the setting set to: "Your SSL/TLS encryption mode is Full".

[image: CloudFlare Settings]

[image: GoDaddy Settings]

Comment: You need to remove GoDaddy NS from GoDaddy

Comment: Worked for me in this case

Comment: Worked for me in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove first two NS from list as they belong to GoDaddy.